# how to parse information out of a CSV file when not all strings are convertable

Tags: python

I am trying to get temperature data within a certain range from a CSV file using

```
temp = [d for d in data if 75 <= float(d["Temperature(F)"]) <= 100]
```

but some of the cells in the file are empty, represented in python with a comma (,), and are not parse-able giving me a "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " error, I have also tried extracting using panda but no no avail, any ideas?

an example of a row of the CSV file:

```
{
        "ID": "A-301",
        "Source": "MapQuest",
        "TMC": "201.0",
        "Severity": "3",
        "Start_Time": "2016-02-19 17:41:00",
        "End_Time": "2016-02-19 21:00:00",
        "Start_Lat": "40.10564",
        "Start_Lng": "-82.949692",
        "End_Lat": "",
        "End_Lng": "",
        "Distance(mi)": "1.28",
        "Description": "Right lane blocked due to accident on I-270 Outerbelt Westbound between Exit 29 OH-3 State St and Exit 27 Cleveland Ave.",
        "Number": "",
        "Street": "Outerbelt W",
        "Side": "R",
        "City": "Columbus",
        "County": "Franklin",
        "State": "OH",
        "Zipcode": "43229",
        "Country": "US",
        "Timezone": "US/Eastern",
        "Airport_Code": "KOSU",
        "Weather_Timestamp": "2016-02-19 17:53:00",
        "Temperature(F)": "57.0",
        "Wind_Chill(F)": "",
        "Humidity(%)": "49.0",
        "Pressure(in)": "29.82",
        "Visibility(mi)": "10.0",
        "Wind_Direction": "SSW",
        "Wind_Speed(mph)": "15.0",
        "Precipitation(in)": "",
        "Weather_Condition": "Clear",
        "Amenity": "False",
        "Bump": "False",
        "Crossing": "False",
        "Give_Way": "False",
        "Junction": "False",
        "No_Exit": "False",
        "Railway": "False",
        "Roundabout": "False",
        "Station": "False",
        "Stop": "False",
        "Traffic_Calming": "False",
        "Traffic_Signal": "False",
        "Turning_Loop": "False",
        "Sunrise_Sunset": "Day",
        "Civil_Twilight": "Day",
        "Nautical_Twilight": "Day",
        "Astronomical_Twilight": "Day"
    },
```

Comment: Hi interesting, I wonder if there's an entry with a badly formatted float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to blow this up into a loop to check if the value exists before trying to convert it to a float. I don't believe you will be able to do this with list comprehension.

```
data = [{'Temperature(F)': 57.0}, {'Temperature(F)': ''}, {'Temperature(F)': 89.0}]

for d in data:
    if d["Temperature(F)"]:
        if 75 <= float(d["Temperature(F)"]) <= 100:
            temps.append(d["Temperature(F)"])
```

Output:

```
temps
#[89.0]
```

If you would like to simply adjust the type stored to `float()` when the match occurs;

```
for d in data:
    if d["Temperature(F)"]:
        if 75 <= float(d["Temperature(F)"]) <= 100:
            d["Temperature(F)"] = float(d["Temperature(F)"])
```

Output:

```
data
#[{'Temperature(F)': '57.0'}, {'Temperature(F)': ''}, {'Temperature(F)': 89.0}]
```

Comment: thats a great way to get an isolated list of just the temperatures as a float, but I am trying to just transform the original data set into float, as I need the other information in the sub set like the weather conditions and whether it was at a stop or not, I dont think that can be done with an isolated list

Comment: Updated answer, it updates original value in dict to float if the match occurs, is this what you're looking for?